# Outlook: how to set recurrence every 1st, 2nd, and 4th week

Tags: outlook, calendar, recurrence, appointment

I've set up two recurring events in Outlook for my team:

- **Event #1**: Every week on Thursdays
- **Event #2**: Every third Friday of the month

With this setup, it will look like the following on my monthly calendar:

```
1 = Event #1
2 = Event #2
| S | M | T | W | T | F | S |
|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
| - | - | - | - | 1 | - | - |
| - | - | - | - | 1 | - | - |
| - | - | - | - | 1 | 2 | - |
|_-_|_-_|_-_|_-_|_1_|_-_|_-_|
```

However, I'd like to have it where *Event #1* only recurs every 1st, 2nd, and 4th week so it doesn't conflict with *Event #2* - like so:

```
| S | M | T | W | T | F | S |
|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
| - | - | - | - | 1 | - | - |
| - | - | - | - | 1 | - | - |
| - | - | - | - | - | 2 | - |
|_-_|_-_|_-_|_-_|_1_|_-_|_-_|
```

The only solution that I found, so far, is to create three separate *Event #1* to recur on those week. That would be impractical for me because if there was a change in the schedule or someone else is added to the events, I'd have to update it three times.

Is it possible to set **Event #1** to recur every 1st, 2nd, and 4th week of the month without having to create three duplicate events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook does not do that kind of recurrence pattern out of the box. The only other solution I can imagine is creating a weekly recurrence pattern and deleting all instances on every third week. But that will preclude you from having "no-end" appointments.